# Android Kotlin: Realm many to one relation

Tags: android, kotlin, realm

I have trouble with the management with one-to-many relations between Kotlin objects using Realm. I don't understand how to do some insert or update.

Here my two objects with one-to-many relation between exam and career.

```
open class Career : RealmObject() {

    @PrimaryKey
    var id: Long = 1
    var status: String = CareerStatus.ACTIVE.value
    var careerName: String? = null
    var exams: RealmList<Exam>? = null
}

open class Exam : RealmObject() {

    @PrimaryKey
    var id: Long = 1
    var teachers: String? = null
    var lode: Boolean? = null
    var score: String = ""
    var exam: String = ""
    var examDescription: String? = null
    var date: Date = Date()
    var cfu: Long = Long.MIN_VALUE
    @LinkingObjects("exams")
    val career: RealmResults<Career>? = null
}
```

Here the two class Manager the manage the read/write on Realm

```
class CareerManager : DatabaseManager() {
    fun findActiveCareer(): Career? {
        return realm.where(Career::class.java).equalTo("status", CareerStatus.ACTIVE.value).findFirst()
    }

    fun insertExamInCareer(exam: Exam) {
        realm.executeTransaction {
            var activeCareer: Career = findActiveCareer()
                    ?: throw Resources.NotFoundException("No active career found")

            activeCareer.exams?.add(exam)
            realm.copyToRealmOrUpdate(exam)
        }
    }

    fun closeActiveCareer() {
        realm.executeTransaction {
            val activeCareer: Career = findActiveCareer()
                    ?: throw Resources.NotFoundException("No active career found")

            activeCareer.status = CareerStatus.TERMINATED.value
        }
    }
}

class ExamManager : DatabaseManager() {

    fun findAll(): List<Exam> {
        val findAll = realm.where(Exam::class.java).findAll()

        return realm.copyFromRealm(findAll).toList()
    }

    fun findAllActive(): List<Exam> {
        val findAll = realm.where(Exam::class.java).equalTo("career.status", CareerStatus.ACTIVE.value).findAll()

        return realm.copyFromRealm(findAll).toList()
    }

    fun insert(exam: Exam): Long {
        realm.beginTransaction()
        var newId: Long = 1

        if (realm.where(Exam::class.java).max("id") != null) {
            newId = realm.where(Exam::class.java).max("id") as Long + 2
        }

        val examToSave = realm.createObject(Exam::class.java, newId)
        examToSave.exam = exam.exam
        examToSave.examDescription = exam.examDescription
        examToSave.date = exam.date
        examToSave.teachers = exam.teachers
        examToSave.score = exam.score
        examToSave.lode = exam.lode
        examToSave.cfu = exam.cfu

        realm.commitTransaction()

        CareerManager().updateCareerExam(findAll())

        return newId

    }
}
```

In my application I need to insert some exams in my career that is actually in ACTIVE state. For the insert I use **CareerManager().insertExamInCareer(exam)** this call (before I try to use **ExamManager().insert(exam)** but doesn't work).

Another use case is when I need to close a career and add the exam to another career. I do this in this manner

**CareerManager().closeActiveCareer()**

**CareerManager().createCareer()**

**CareerManager().insertExamInCareer(exam)**
[image: Here the result]

The exam in the two career are the same, but they had to be different and in Exam there must have been two records, not one